# JAXB serialization: creating node from class name

Tags: java, xml, generics, jaxb

Here's a deal:
Let's say I have a class *with generics*, something like this:

```
public class Item<K,V>{

private K key;
private V value;
// some constructors/getters/setters here:
{...}
```

To be specific let's consider this object:

```
Item<String, SomeEnum> someItem = new Item<>("LolString", SomeEnum.SomeEnumValue).
```

This is default serialization:

```
<item>
    <key xsi:type="xs:string">LolString</key>
    <value xsi:type="someEnum">SomeEnumValue</value>
</item>
```

How can I instead of xsi:type attribute create a tree with nodes with the names of the classes which are passed to generics, like this:

```
<item>
    <key>
        <String>LolString</string>
    </key>
    <value>
        <someEnum>SomeEnumValue</someEnum>
    </value>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a limited set of classes, you can use the `@XmlElements` annotation to specify, which element name do you want for each class.

Something like:

```
@XmlElements(
    @XmlElement(name="String", type=String.class),
    @XmlElement(name="someEnum", type=SomeEnum.class)
}
```

However it's hard to say if this will work for you with your `Item` class. I think `@XmlElements` for some reason requires the property to be a collection so you'll have something like:

```
@XmlElements(
    @XmlElement(name="String", type=String.class),
    @XmlElement(name="someEnum", type=SomeEnum.class)
}
private List<Serializable> key;
```

which may not be want you really want.

But this is a pure annotations solution.

Comment: It works if you encapsulate key and value in some GenericClass<K>:
    private GenericClass<K> key;
    private GenericClass<V> value;
and do the @XmlElements stuff inside. And it is actually somewhat legitimate solution for the project, so thank you. Though it would be great to find general case solution

Answer (score 0):

In your XSD, make key and value a complex type with a choice of various elements: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_choice.asp

Comment: Is there a way to resolve my question only using jaxb annotations?